# How to access wordpress database using aws server

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, rds

How can I access wordpress database using aws server. Currently, an existing website in running online and the server used is aws. We need to update something and we need the db to run into our local and dev site. I have tried using aws on other website but this one which is a wordpress site, the database cannot be found on the aws rds. So I'm thinking the db is added somewhere in the FTP (maybe phpmyadmin folder) but I don't know how to get and find it. How can I solve this one?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing, Wordpress uses MySQL as its database. This is defined in wp-config.php

You can edit that file to change which database WordPress is using https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Set_Database_Host

Comment: Yes, config is defined but it only shows like this.

`define('DB_NAME', 'sampledb');`

`define('DB_USER', 'sampleuser');`


`define('DB_PASSWORD', 'samplepassword');`

`define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');`

The host should not be localhost. Maybe the the db is just inside the server because is using localhost.
On my other website that is using aws. The host is using the endpoint which like this example `example.appstream.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
`

Comment: If it is set to localhost then you are using a locally installed mysql and not RDS. If you want to use to RDS you will have to create a mysql database in RDS then migrate the data and change your endpoint to the RDS endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer guys, most of you are correct. It was installed locally, I already access it using shh. I'm using windows so I used putty.